# max column value in postgres by distinct date;

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-values

I have a table which has a column name timestamp and energy where data is being inserted in both columns.Something like this

```
       timestamp               energy
 2017-10-28 17:35:05.45144  |  40.21
 2017-10-28 17:30:07.375661 |  36.21
 2017-10-28 17:25:05.677181 |  36.21
 2017-10-28 17:20:08.422317 |  36.21

 2017-10-27 17:35:06.661601 |  39.21
 2017-10-27 17:30:05.003008 |  39.19
 2017-10-27 17:25:05.251989 |  39.17
 2017-10-27 17:20:04.976132 |  39.13

 2017-10-26 17:35:06.661601 |  37.21
 2017-10-26 17:30:05.003008 |  37.19
 2017-10-26 17:25:05.251989 |  37.17
 2017-10-26 17:20:04.976132 |  37.13
```

and so on
I want to fetch max energy value by each date in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `date_trunc()`.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank You so much It took me only 20 sec to think after your hint, Thanks a lot. Query is here SELECT timestamp::date,max(m_e) FROM delta_energdata GROUP BY timestamp::date;